# Polygons in google maps heatmap layer

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, heatmap

I'm trying to create heatmap consisting of polygons instead of points. 
I create points using google.map.LatLng class and Polygon using Polygon class(code below)

```
const createPolygon = polygon => {
    const points = polygon.geometry.coordinates[0].map(point => {
        return new window.google.maps.LatLng(point[0], point[1]); // [lat, lng]
    });
    return new google.maps.Polygon({ // eslint-disable-line
        paths: points
    });
```

};

Then i render it with HeatmapLayer component from react-google-maps library(don't think it matters though).

```
 <HeatmapLayer data={heatmapData.map(createPolygon)} />
```

Unfortunately I'm getting errors like this.

```
{message: "not an Array or MVCArray", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new mc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:294:16)"}

Uncaught TypeError: b.lat is not a function
```

I have also tried this aproach

```
<HeatmapLayer data={new google.maps.MVCArray(data)} />
```

But then again I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: b.lat is not a function
```

Do i have to create Polygon in some whacky way or is it straight impossible to acompplish what I'm trying to do?

Any help and tips will be appreciated

Comment: you need to pass the points to the heatmap `createPolygon.getPath()` ... but I think theres some disconnect between point data and polygon data.

Comment: Wouldn't i get heatmap with points same as corners of polygon?

Comment: You would, Is that what your going for? I see polygon data as perimeter or area and heat maps as point density data. Like i said the `getPath()` will give you the array of points from the polygon. Note: polygons first and last points are always the same. ie squares return 5 points.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I didin't want to do it this way. If i did i would get hostpots on the corners of polygon and empty spots in center instead of having surfaces with same weight. I went other route - interpolating those polygons with points

Answer (score 0):

Heatmap needs the data needs to be defined as an array of LatLng objects

e.g.

```
var heatmapData = [
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435)
        ];
```

You can also provide it with an array of a mixture of WeightedLocation and LatLng objects

e.g

```
var heatMapData = [
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), weight: 0.5},
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443), weight: 2},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441), weight: 3},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439), weight: 2},
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435), weight: 0.5},

  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447), weight: 3},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445), weight: 2},
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441), weight: 0.5},
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437), weight: 2},
  {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435), weight: 3}
];
```

**Try this function:**

```
const createPolygon = polygon => {
    const points = polygon.geometry.coordinates[0].map(point => {
        return new window.google.maps.LatLng(point[0], point[1]); // [lat,lng]
    });
    return points;
}
```

This will return an array of LatLng object which will work for the heatmap